# How can I do the translation? to do this?

Tags: javascript, translation

I create two variables, named variable1 and variable2

I store an English word, cat, in variable1, and Google translation service translates "cat" to the French word, "chat", and stores it in variable2

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/translate/ You would need to use the google translate API, and they do charge.